# PyTorch CUDA - .to(device) for Text

Tags: pytorch, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to get my PyTorch model to be completely running on my GPU; however, I've ran into an issue and I'm unsure how to solve this.

Right now I have a set of image text pairs that I want to feed into a CLIP transformer; however, usually what I did was get the image and convert it into a tensor, but that does not make sense to me in the case of a transformer since it transformers already encode the text into vector representations.

Am I supposed to pass the text immediately into the transformer without specifiying it ".to(device)" or am I supposed to encode it before passing it into the transformer? Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks

Trying to set it up, but does not make sense to me.

Comment: Floating point numbers are the language of neural nets. Tokenizers convert text into "tokens", each token is a float. Often times, but not 100% percent of the time, a token will be equal to a word. For example, "I love programming", "I" might be "1", "love" might be "2", and "programming" might be "3". The complete sentence tokenized would be [1, 2, 3]. You will need to find the tokenizer that your model was trained with, and feed your text through that. https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter2/4?fw=pt